# How to pass values and make multiple callbacks in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am a beginner to javascript syntax and I'm trying to understand asynchronous callbacks in nodejs. I'm trying to execute this small piece of code which contains 2 basic functions one after the other.

```js
function compute (n1,n2,callback){
    callback(n1,n2);
}
function sum(n1,n2,callback){
    console.log(n1+n2);
    callback(n1,n2);
}
function product(n1,n2){
    console.log(n1*n2);
}



compute(5, 3, function() {
    sum(function (){
        product();
    });
});
```

I get the following error after I try to run it.

```
C:\Users\HP\Nodejs\node-example\node-infile-module\practice.js:10
    callback(n1,n2);
    ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at sum (C:\Users\HP\Nodejs\node-example\node-infile-module\practice.js:10:5)
    at C:\Users\HP\Nodejs\node-example\node-infile-module\practice.js:19:5
    at compute (C:\Users\HP\Nodejs\node-example\node-infile-module\practice.js:6:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\Nodejs\node-example\node-infile-module\practice.js:18:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

As nodejs supports closure property which automatically uses the parameters from parent functions without  needing to explicitly mentioning, I dont understand why it is not considering my function as a callback. Also I want to implement error first approach after I get this basic right. I read other stackoverflow answers but they seemed too complex. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide parameters to the `sum` function *(right now, you are passing a function as `n1` and that's it)* and the `product` function:

```js
function compute (n1,n2,callback){
    callback(n1,n2);
}
function sum(n1,n2,callback){
    console.log(n1+n2);
    callback(n1,n2);
}
function product(n1,n2){
    console.log(n1*n2);
}
//                     v   v
compute(5, 3, function(n1, n2) {
    sum(n1, n2, product);
    //  ^   ^      ^
});
```

Comment: Why isn't it working if i directly call compute(5,3, sum(...)); instead of enclosing it in a new function with args and then calling it?..

Comment: Because when you do `compute(5, 3, sum);`, you are passing a callback (a function). When you do `compute(5, 3, sum(...));`, you are calling `sum`, getting its return value (`undefined`) and passing it to `compute`. Enclosing it with an anonymous function makes it possible for `compute` to call that function and give it parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
function compute (n1,n2,callback){
    callback(n1,n2);
}
function sum(n1,n2,callback){
    console.log(n1+n2);
    callback(n1,n2);
}
function product(n1,n2){
    console.log(n1*n2);
}

compute(5, 3, function() {
    var arg1 = 5;
    var arg2 = 5;
    // The sum function: type of `third argment` is `function`
    sum(arg1, arg2, function (){
        product();
    });
});
```

**Updated**

```
var arg1 = 5;
var arg2 = 5;
sum(arg1, arg2, function (){
```

Comment: You forgot to provide parameters to `product();`

Comment: But what is it with the closure property?.. I read that theres no need to explicitly pass params to child functions.. doesn't that mean we can ignore passing args?..

Comment: If you pass the name of the function, yes, there is no need:  `compute(5, 3, sum);` This will work fine. But in your example, you create a brand new anonymous function which does not have `n1` or `n2` declared anywhere in its context

Comment: yea i initially tried compute(5,3,sum);. But I want product function to be called as a callback to the sum. Thats where i could'nt figure out how to make multiple callbacks with just passing name of the functions.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the arguments through the callbacks.

```js
function compute(n1, n2, callback) {
  callback(n1, n2);
}
function sum(n1, n2, callback) {
  console.log(n1 + n2);
  callback(n1, n2);
}
function product(n1, n2) {
  console.log(n1 * n2);
}

compute(5, 3, function (arg1, arg2) {
  sum(arg1, arg2, function (arg1, arg2) {
    product(arg1, arg2);
  });
});
```

Comment: Why isn't it working if i directly call compute(5,3, sum(...)); instead of enclosing it in a new function with args and then calling it?..